# Counting instances of a string in a nested ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains

In the below example, how would I go about counting the amount of times 'YES' occurs and depending on how many times it occurs, store a value to a variable? e.g. if 'YES' occurs once 10, twice 30, etc. I'm quite new to data structures and I feel I maybe going about this the wrong way. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Details {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        al1.add("hi");
        al1.add("How are you");
        al1.add("Good Morning");
        al1.add("bye");
        al1.add("Good night");

    ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al2.add("Howdy");
    al2.add("Good Evening");
    al2.add("bye");
    al2.add("Good night");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al4 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    al4.add(al1);

    // Storing the comparison output in ArrayList<String>
    ArrayList<String> al3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String temp : al1)
        al3.add(al2.contains(temp) ? "Yes" : "No");
    System.out.println(al3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al4 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    int totalSize = 0 ;

    for ( inti = 0 ; i < al4.size() ; i++ )
    {
         ArrayList<String>> nested_al4 = al4.get(i);

         for ( inti = 0 ; i < nested_al4.size() ; i++ )
         {
               totalSize ++
         }
    }

    System.out.println(totalSize );
```